# Stripe Credit Card not working on Woocommerce modal checkout

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, stripe-payments

I want to use the Stripe checkout into a modal instead of a checkout page but when the `[woocommerce_checkout]` shortcode move to the modal the Stripe checkout form gets disabled and it's completely working as page checkout.

Here is the main function like below

```
add_action( 'wp_ajax_getCheckoutPageContent', 'getCheckoutPageContentCallBack' );
add_action( 'wp_ajax_nopriv_getCheckoutPageContent', 'getCheckoutPageContentCallBack' );

function getCheckoutPageContentCallBack() {
    $product_id        = absint( $_POST['product_id'] );
    $quantity          = absint( $_POST['quantity'] );
    $product_status    = get_post_status( $product_id );
    $passed_validation = apply_filters( 'woocommerce_add_to_cart_validation', true, $product_id, $quantity );

    if ( WC()->cart->add_to_cart( $product_id, $quantity ) ) {
        do_action( 'woocommerce_ajax_added_to_cart', $product_id );
        global $woocommerce;
        $items = $woocommerce->cart->get_cart();

        wc_setcookie( 'woocommerce_items_in_cart', count( $items ) );
        wc_setcookie( 'woocommerce_cart_hash', md5( json_encode( $items ) ) );
        do_action( 'woocommerce_set_cart_cookies', true );

        define( 'WOOCOMMERCE_CHECKOUT', true );
        echo do_shortcode('[woocommerce_checkout]');

    }else{
        define( 'WOOCOMMERCE_CHECKOUT', true );
        echo do_shortcode('[woocommerce_checkout]');
    }
    die();
}
```

And the modal below

```
<!-- Start Booking Popup Modal Area -->
<div class="booking-popup-modal-area modal right fade" id="Booking-Popup-Modal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="Booking-Popup-Modal" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <button type="button" class="btn-close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
            <div class="modal-body">
                <div id="checkOutPageContent">

                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
    function customCheckout(event){
        var wp_ajax_url="<?php echo site_url();?>/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php";
        var data = {
            action: 'getCheckoutPageContent',
            product_id: jQuery(event.target).data('productid'),
            quantity: 1
        };

        jQuery.post( wp_ajax_url, data, function(content) {
            jQuery("#checkOutPageContent").html(content);
            jQuery("#Booking-Popup-Modal").modal('show');

        });
    }

</script>
<!-- End Booking Popup Modal Area -->
```

The complete issue you can see in the below screenshot

[image]

I can't understand anything and didn't find any suitable solution on the web.

What should I do now, please?

What I am missing there?

Thanks

Comment: Are you using this plugin? https://woocommerce.com/products/stripe/ You might want to reach out to WooCommerce since they owns this plugin. I can't see the inspected div `stripe-card-element` in your code so it's highly possible inside the plugin code

Comment: Everything is working when I put this into a page but when it using in a modal it's not working! @orakaro

Comment: I believe this div is inserted as an iframe. So it is expected to not working in a modal